# Degree of field extension is infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

If we have the field extension $\mathbb{Q}\leq \mathbb{R}$, could you explain me why it stands that $[\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q}]=+\infty$ ??

Comment: For fun, try proving that $[\mathbb{A}:\mathbb{Q}]$ is infinite, where $\mathbb{A}$ is the set of algebraic numbers. I think this is more interesting because $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{A}$ is an algebraic extension. The extension $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is not even algebraic, so it is automatically infinite.

Answer (score 10):

One way to see this is that any finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ will be countable (being a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable, it cannot be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Could you explain me further why any finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ will be countable??

Comment: @MaryStar: As Tobias said, if $K$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb Q,$ then it will be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q.$ In particular, it will be isomorphic to $\Bbb Q^n$ for some finite $n.$ Hence, since a finite product of countable sets is countable, while $\Bbb R$ is not, then we're done.

Comment: @CameronBuie What does it mean that $K$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?? Does it mean that there are $a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n \in K$ which form the basis??

Comment: @Mary: Yes, that is what it means. Do you know why a finite extension of $\Bbb Q$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$?

Answer (score 7):

Another way: since $\pi$ is trascendental, no polynomial of $\Bbb Q[X]$ has $\Bbb R$ as its descomposition field.